# How to install cups-pdf?

Tags: high-sierra, pdf, homebrew

I'm trying to install CUPS-PDF for Mac by Homebrew as follow:

```
$ brew install cups-pdf
Error: No available formula with the name "cups-pdf" 
It was migrated from caskroom/cask to homebrew/core.
```

but there is an error that it has been migrated to `homebrew/core` which I'm trying to install from.

In this case, what would be the proper method of installing it?

Comment: There are often other places that aren’t as official that package these. You could google around for them. There are quite a few resources but they aren’t going to be as well supported.

Comment: looks like a side effects of the effort to merge the recipes from caskroom to the core repositories... let me check

Comment: Running `brew update` didn't help.

Comment: I would say go with the installation as suggested in the answer (it's the official download repository, you get there from the package website: https://www.cups-pdf.de/welcome.shtml in the download section). Looks like in the migration the formula vanished... better to warn the brew maintainer

Comment: The formula was moved to the "homebrew/boneyard" repository, that is really a kind of "graveyard" for formulas, because "it needs write-access to SIP protected locations"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried installing it from this [Bitbucket repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726043520/https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/wiki/Home)

There the following instructions are given:

> Installation (10.6+)
>
> - Install the [package](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726053404/https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/downloads/).
> - Open System Preferences and go to Printing.
> - Click on Add Printer (the + at the bottom).
> - "CUPS-PDF" should be in the list, select it.
> - Select "Postscript" from the "Print Using" menu and pick "Generic postscript color printer"
> - Click Add
>
> If your OS is incompatible with the package version, install anyway.
> Then follow the steps in [here](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/SetupNullPrinterOnMac) to setup a null printer and follow the
> steps in [here](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/AddingAPrinterOnTheMac) to add this null printer to the printer list.

Answer (score 8):

I've tested [instructions provided at Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/wiki/Home), but doesn't seem to work on High Sierra as per:

> This package is incompatible with this version of macOS and may fail to install.

See: [OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) Package Installation Failed](https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/issues/57/osx-1011-el-capitan-package-installation).

So instead, I've followed the instructions at [*farmerswife* article](https://farmerswife.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/17000051974-pdf-print-setup) and installed PDFwriter instead:

1. Download and install the [Lisanet PDFwriter installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfwriterformac/) as per instructions
2. After installing the *PDFWriter* package, go back and *Show Package Contents*.
3. From the installer, uncompress *Archive.pax.gz* and copy *`PDFwriter.ppd`* file into `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources`.
4. Now go to the Printers dialog and add the printer, choosing the *Lisanet* driver as explained in the documentation.

Source: [PDF printing results in "empty" or "zero bytes size" PDF](https://support.farmerswife.com/support/solutions/articles/17000062134-pdf-printing-results-in-empty-or-zero-bytes-size-pdf).

Comment: Thanks kenorb to propagate the post I put on bitbucket some minutes ago. It will help many more people ;-)
https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/issues/57/osx-1011-el-capitan-package-installation

Comment: No worries. I've tested the instructions, seems the installation works fine, better than CupsPDF, but it'll take a while when I log out my user to see whether it actually works fully, as I usually restart or logout once a month when I got some random kernel crash.

Comment: For those who don't find the Library folder, it is hidden by default. Just click shift+command+"." and you will see it.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm for https://github.com/rodyager/RWTS-PDFwriter

It works on Monterey 12.0.1 with Native Mac apps.
But get issue with printing from Wine app (DipTrace).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Alternative that Works Nov 2020 on Catalina

https://github.com/rodyager/RWTS-PDFwriter

Comment: Link-only answers tend to gather downvotes as they make it hard for anybody to assess the usefullnes of the answer without clicking on the link. Your answer may be better received if you explain how the page you link to helps to install CUPS-PDF as asked for in the question, or why CUPS-PDF isn't an option and what the linked page/software offers instead.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023:

Repo on Bitbacker it's not avalable, so the solution is install MacPorts [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)

and after this run install command in your terminal `sudo port install cups-pdf`

[image]

To install PPD profile:

1. run this in terminal: `cupsctl WebInterface=yes`
2. Access via Browser to `http://127.0.0.1:631/`
3. Add new printer / Edit exist one
4. Press open file, press cmd+shift+g and enter this path `/opt/local/share/cups/model/` and select `CUPS-PDF.ppd` file.

[image]
[image]

Regards